# Web scraping for an android app

Tags: android, web-scraping

I am doing my final year project to build an app for providing college events notification to its users.the app have to provide registration facility to the participants(only my college students) using their roll number.For the purpose of validating their roll no ,i want to scrap   my college website(particularly students site where each student have their own login in with their roll no).As i am new to android platform and scraping ,can someone give clear idea or details for this.

Comment: You need to use JSOUP which does the job in android.. or Use a Html  simple dom parser in php to create a json. This json can be used in  android

Comment: Simple HTML DOM parser would be easy,if you have basic knowledge with PHP.

Comment: Did you try DOM parser or JSOUP ?